# Working system, blank screen

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, busybox, syslinux

### Setup

Partitions:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
...
Device     Boot Start    End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048  51199   49152  24M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2       51200 204799  153600  75M 83 Linux
```

[Syslinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Syslinux) configuration:

```
UI menu.c32
LABEL linux
        LINUX ../bzImage
        INITRD ../initrd.img
        APPEND rootfstype=tmpfs init=/init
```

`/init`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
mount -a
/bin/sh
poweroff -f
```

### Testing

Booting via QEMU works:

```
# qemu-system-x86_64 /dev/sda
```

...However, running on a laptop (same arch) results in a blank screen. I can type shell commands (`reboot`, `poweroff`, etc.), but no text appears onscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `nomodeset` to the kernel's command line solved the problem. I believe it worked in the VM because QEMU handles graphics differently than "bare metal".